# Hyper-V with Debian Stretch Error

Tags: debian, hyper-v

I'm getting the following error on a base install of Debian Stretch:

```
May  2 09:51:03 HAProxyMon kernel: [  242.656604] Workqueue: hv_vmbus_con vmbus_onmessage_work [hv_vmbus]
May  2 09:51:03 HAProxyMon kernel: [  242.656607]  ffff9feab6949000 ffff9feab691b800 ffff9feab6841100 ffff9feabd6581c0
May  2 09:51:03 HAProxyMon kernel: [  242.656612]  ffff9feab3de7000 ffffc21040653c40 ffffffffa51f6403 0000000000000000
May  2 09:51:03 HAProxyMon kernel: [  242.656615]  0000000000000000 ffff9feabd6581c0 ffffffffa4e8091e ffff9feab6841100
May  2 09:51:03 HAProxyMon kernel: [  242.656619] Call Trace:
May  2 09:51:03 HAProxyMon kernel: [  242.656634]  [<ffffffffa51f6403>] ? __schedule+0x233/0x6d0
May  2 09:51:03 HAProxyMon kernel: [  242.656639]  [<ffffffffa4e8091e>] ? __kernfs_remove+0x11e/0x250
May  2 09:51:03 HAProxyMon kernel: [  242.656646]  [<ffffffffa51f68d2>] ? schedule+0x32/0x80
May  2 09:51:03 HAProxyMon kernel: [  242.656650]  [<ffffffffa51f9ca3>] ? schedule_timeout+0x243/0x310
May  2 09:51:03 HAProxyMon kernel: [  242.656657]  [<ffffffffa4f2ace5>] ? kobject_release+0x65/0x180
May  2 09:51:03 HAProxyMon kernel: [  242.656662]  [<ffffffffa506850a>] ? device_destroy+0x3a/0x40
May  2 09:51:03 HAProxyMon kernel: [  242.656665]  [<ffffffffa51f72e1>] ? wait_for_completion+0xf1/0x130
May  2 09:51:03 HAProxyMon kernel: [  242.656673]  [<ffffffffa4ca17f0>] ? wake_up_q+0x70/0x70
May  2 09:51:03 HAProxyMon kernel: [  242.656679]  [<ffffffffc060e30c>] ? util_remove+0x1c/0x40 [hv_utils]
May  2 09:51:03 HAProxyMon kernel: [  242.656684]  [<ffffffffc0361023>] ? vmbus_remove+0x23/0x30 [hv_vmbus]
May  2 09:51:03 HAProxyMon kernel: [  242.656688]  [<ffffffffa506c74a>] ? __device_release_driver+0x9a/0x150
May  2 09:51:03 HAProxyMon kernel: [  242.656692]  [<ffffffffa506c81e>] ? device_release_driver+0x1e/0x30
May  2 09:51:03 HAProxyMon kernel: [  242.656695]  [<ffffffffa506be75>] ? bus_remove_device+0xf5/0x160
May  2 09:51:03 HAProxyMon kernel: [  242.656698]  [<ffffffffa5068307>] ? device_del+0x127/0x260
May  2 09:51:03 HAProxyMon kernel: [  242.656701]  [<ffffffffa5068456>] ? device_unregister+0x16/0x60
May  2 09:51:03 HAProxyMon kernel: [  242.656706]  [<ffffffffc0365d68>] ? vmbus_onoffer_rescind+0xd8/0x100 [hv_vmbus]
May  2 09:51:03 HAProxyMon kernel: [  242.656711]  [<ffffffffc036216e>] ? vmbus_onmessage_work+0x1e/0x30 [hv_vmbus]
May  2 09:51:03 HAProxyMon kernel: [  242.656715]  [<ffffffffa4c90384>] ? process_one_work+0x184/0x410
May  2 09:51:03 HAProxyMon kernel: [  242.656717]  [<ffffffffa4c9065d>] ? worker_thread+0x4d/0x480
May  2 09:51:03 HAProxyMon kernel: [  242.656720]  [<ffffffffa4c90610>] ? process_one_work+0x410/0x410
May  2 09:51:03 HAProxyMon kernel: [  242.656722]  [<ffffffffa4c90610>] ? process_one_work+0x410/0x410
May  2 09:51:03 HAProxyMon kernel: [  242.656726]  [<ffffffffa4c965ce>] ? kthread+0xce/0xf0
May  2 09:51:03 HAProxyMon kernel: [  242.656731]  [<ffffffffa4c24701>] ? __switch_to+0x2c1/0x6c0
May  2 09:51:03 HAProxyMon kernel: [  242.656734]  [<ffffffffa4c96500>] ? kthread_park+0x60/0x60
May  2 09:51:03 HAProxyMon kernel: [  242.656738]  [<ffffffffa51fb2f5>] ? ret_from_fork+0x25/0x30
```

When this happens, the system is unable to reboot and who knows what else.

The system is configured with Dynamic Memory with a range from 512 to 4096. Hyper-V is on a SAN.

It appears this bug was in Ubuntu: [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1682561)

Is there anything I can look at to get this fixed in Debian?

Comment: Could this be related to Dynamic Memory being used? Debian didn't support it in Jessie, maybe there is support in Stretch, but I've not tested it.